# Typescript - optional type if generic is not provided

Tags: typescript, generics, interface, option-type

I Would like  **optionalFields** to have type of `OptionalFieldsByTopic<Topic>` if generic is not provided, otherwise `OptionalFieldsByTopic<T>`.
Thanks for help in advance.

```
export interface ICreateItem<T extends Topic = never> { // T must be optional
   id: string;
   name: string;
   tags: string[];
   collectionId?: string;
   topic: string;
   optionalFields?: OptionalFieldsByTopic<T>; // If T is not provided then this is equal OptionalFieldsByTopic<Topic>
}

type OptionalFieldsByTopic<T extends keyof IOptionalFields> = IOptionalFields[T];
```

OptionalFIeldsByTopic example:

```
const test: OptionalFieldsByTopic<"books"> = { author: "brandon", language: "english" }

export type Topic = keyof IOptionalFields;
```

mockup data:

```
export interface IOptionalFields {
   books: {
      author?: string;
      language?: string;
      translation?: string; 
   };
   vehicle: {
      model?: string;
      type?: string;
      color?: string;
 
   };
   painting: {
      author?: string;
      description?: string;
      image?: string;
   };
}
```

Comment: `I Would like to optionalFields to be type of Topic if generic is not provided`. That makes no sense to me, can you elaborate?

Comment: I edited post. Hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: So it's `T` that should have default type `Topic`, not `optionalFields`. What's the problem with `interface ICreateItem<T extends Topic = Topic>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
export interface ICreateItem<T extends Topic = Topic> {
    ...
}
```